# function parameter type match issue

Tags: types, kotlin

IntelliJ is throwing the following error at me, but for all I can tell, there is no problem.

### Minimal example

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate

// ...

var jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate? = null
// ... relying on dependency injection from Spring
if (jdbcTemplate == null) {
    throw RuntimeException("jdbcTemplate not injected correctly")
}
jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP TABLE customers IF EXISTS")
```

[image: Screen shot of compiler error]

The function has three implementations. One of which accepts a `String`. A string is what I am giving it. So what is up?

I have tried:

- Invalidating cache and restarted IntelloJ
- Building through `./gradlew build`

+

```
:compileKotlin
e: /home/ruben/workspace/campingmanager/src/main/kotlin/hello/Application.kt: (27, 22): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public open fun execute(sql: String!): Unit defined in org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
public open fun <T : Any!> execute(action: ConnectionCallback<(???..???)>!): (???..???) defined in org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
public open fun <T : Any!> execute(action: StatementCallback<(???..???)>!): (???..???) defined in org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
e: /home/ruben/workspace/campingmanager/src/main/kotlin/hello/Application.kt: (28, 22): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public open fun execute(sql: String!): Unit defined in org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
public open fun <T : Any!> execute(action: ConnectionCallback<(???..???)>!): (???..???) defined in org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
public open fun <T : Any!> execute(action: StatementCallback<(???..???)>!): (???..???) defined in org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
:compileKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.113 secs
```

- Getting latest Kotlin version 1.0.2-1

**Kotlin version**: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.0.2

**Kotlin plugin version**: 1.0.2-1-release-IJ145-20

**IntelliJ version**: 2016.1.3

Comment: Have you tried building from command line, i.e. gradle, invalidating idea cache and restarting?
What's the Kotlin compiler version you're using?
What's the Idea Kotlin Plugin version you're using?

Comment: Tried you suggestions and updated my question. No luck

Comment: Can you include code instead of a screenshot, smallest failing example possible?  Possibly you are showing what you think is the problem, but not showing enough so that we can see the problem.

Comment: put the code in the smallest function that causes the problem and show more of it.

Comment: @JaysonMinard done

Comment: Are you sure it is `null` checked in your failing case?  try `jdbcTemplate!!.execute("DROP TABLE customers IF EXISTS")` to confirm that isn't the issue.

Comment: That did the trick. But why? Isn't it supposed to be smart casted?

Comment: Because `jdbcTemplate` can be changed (in theory) from other thread. Also there is issue for this case: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11119

Comment: Right, ok, so changing it to val instead of var might do the trick. Thanks for you assistance. If you formulate this into an answer, I'll mark it as the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is in `jdbcTemplate` -- it can be null, because it can be changed from other thread.
To fix compilation error you should replace your call to this:
`jdbcTemplate!!.execute("DROP TABLE customers IF EXISTS")`.

About unclear error message there is an issue: [KT-11119](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11119).

Also it may be a good idea use `lateinit` for this case. (see [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#late-initialized-properties) for more info.)

Answer (score 0):

Checking with `!!` ugly, instead i suggest this two approaches.

Use `lateinit` which specially added for DI frameworks

```
class Database {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate;

    fun initCustomerDatabase() {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP TABLE customers IF EXISTS")
    }
}
```

Cons: Additional runtime check on every call on `jdbcTemplate`.
Cons: `jdbcTemplate` is mutable.

Use constructor injection:

```
class Database @Autowired constructor(val jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate) {
    fun initCustomerDatabase() {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP TABLE customers IF EXISTS")
    }
}
```

Pros: `jdbcTemplate` immutable
Pros: No runtime checks.

In spring 4.3 you can write following code even without `@Autowired constructor`, example:

```
class Database(val jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate) {
    fun initCustomerDatabase() {
        jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP TABLE customers IF EXISTS")
    }
}
```

Personally i use constructor injection, because it's very useful for testing.